# WordPress migrate sufficient permissions error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange problem, that I have never encountered.

I migrated web-site from my PC to the server. Well, I have done this a lot of times, but never encountered this issue.

Ok, what I did is, i copied the theme and exported the database and imported on the server + I replaced the table prefixes from `wp_` to `site_` to match the servers pre-made WordPress installation prefixes.

The page works fine, but, when I log in as an administrator ( there are no other users, then the admin ) I get this error:

[image]

And when I open the actual page I see this:

[image]
*The white line one the top is where the admin menu should be.*

It seems, that the user has actually logged in, but somehow is getting *rejected* from the server?

I know that this is a small isue that can be solved, by reinstalling WordPress with the exact settings that I have on my local PC, but I want to know why this happened and how to actually fix it.

PS: There are no addons involved in this. Just my custom theme.

Comment: Did you change the prefix in the config file?

Comment: I changed the prefix of the table names to the one, that is written in the `wp-config.php` file. As I said, the side is working exactly as it should, except, that I can't log into admin panel.

Comment: It looks like you're being logged in, but your account doesn't have administrator privileges. Go to your `site_usermeta` table in the database and confirm that the `meta_key` and `meta_value` are using the correct prefix. They should be `site_capabilities`, `site_user_level` etc instead of `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level`. Also make sure that `site_capabilities` is set to administrator.

Comment: I changed that, but I still get the same messages. Any other place, I need to change?

Comment: Check the `site_options` table to see if there are any `option_name`s that are still using `wp_` and not `site_`

Comment: Did that, only two entries for `sidebars_widgets` and `cron`. Changed there, still the same. Should I cang **all of the wp_** entries in the DB to `site_` ?

Comment: Yes, if you changed the prefix in the config file, you need to change it everywhere else as well. See if this post will help you: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/

Comment: Ok, I changed **all** possible entries from `wp_` to `site_` and it works now. Please combine your comments into an answer so I can give you credit. Thanx already.

Comment: Done! Glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're being logged in, but your account doesn't have administrator privileges. Go to your `site_usermeta` table in the database and confirm that the `meta_key` and `meta_value` are using the correct prefix. They should be `site_capabilities`, `site_user_level` etc instead of `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level` etc. Also make sure that `site_capabilities` is set to administrator.

Additionally, check the `site_options` table to see if there are any `option_name`s that are still using `wp_` and not `site_` **Essentially, if you changed the prefix in the config file, you will need to change all entries of the prefix in your MySQL database as well.**

Here's a good resource to follow: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-to-improve-security/